# PHP syntax eroor

Tags: php, mysql

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$user' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\home\login.php on line 4

```
    <?php

$host = "localhost"
$user = "root";    <------ line 4
$pass = "";
$db = "table";

mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
mysql_select_db($db);

if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password']; 

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
    $res = mysql_query($sql);

    if (mysql_num_rows($res) == 1) {
        echo "Super";
        exit();
    } else {
        echo "Siper";
        exit();
    }
}

?>
```

How can resolved this?

Comment: Fix the error in line 3 (what is missing directly before `$user`?)

Comment: missing semi colon on `$host = "localhost"`

Comment: Consider using an IDE such as NetBeans, Eclipse or PHP Storm to help detect these errors without needing to run any code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a semicolon on the first line. Remember that in php,  errors often refer to something *around* the line number stated, and not necessarily **on** the line. :)

i.e.

```
 $host = "localhost";
```

Edit:

You may also want to sanitize your $_POST data, or re-think the way you're structuring this, as otherwise you're leaving things open to SQL injection.

Take a read through here for more information:
[What's the best method for sanitizing user input with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php)

Comment: Good spot on the additional problems! `:-)`

Answer (score 1):

Missing semicolon:

```
 <?php

$host = "localhost"; <--- error :D
$user = "root";    <------ line 4
$pass = "";
$db = "table";

mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
mysql_select_db($db);

if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password']; 

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
    $res = mysql_query($sql);

    if (mysql_num_rows($res) == 1) {
        echo "Super";
        exit();
    } else {
        echo "Siper";
        exit();
    }
}

?>
```